# convert String to XML type (Element type)

Tags: java, xml, string, document

I want to convert a String to Element type. The 'strXML' is a String which has an XML message.

I tried this:

```
  DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(strXML)));
  Element elem = doc.getDocumentElement();
```

But this is showing the errror during parse, mentioned below:

rg.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 911; The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

Can anybody tell me what can be the reason of this and if there is any other way to do this.

Comment: Show the input string contents. Otherwise nobody can possibly help you.

Comment: Can you please provide the input string that would actually add to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message gives you a big clue:

```
 lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 911
```

This means that at position 911 in the input string the parser found `<?XML...`

It appears that your input string contains more than one XML document